# What do you do if your Shabbos host serves chocolate chip challah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching, derech-eretz-manners, challah-shabbat-bread

Based on [this shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/759117/Rabbi_Zvi_Sobolofsky/The_Correct_Brechas_on_Chocolate_Chip_Challah) from R. Sobolofsky, chocolate chip challah is no different from chocolate babka or other cake and thus has the bracha of mezonos

If that is the case, one would only be able to make ha-motzei on such challah if he is koevia seudah on it. According to R. Yaakov Luban's [article](http://web.archive.org/web/http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/the_mezonos_roll_is_it_a_piece_of_cake_by_rabbi_yaakov_luban) "The Mezonos Roll... Is It a Piece of Cake?", footnote 8, there are three ways in which one can be koveiah seudah on mezonos:

1. You eat an average person's full meal's worth of just that mezonos.
2. You eat what is enough for you personally to be satisfied for an entire meal.
3. You treat the mezonos as bread and eat enough of it along with other foods to be equivalent in amount to a regular meal with bread and other foods.

So the problem is: if you hold position 1) or 2), there might not be enough of the mezonos for you to fulfill the requirement (especially at a large dinner where everyone just gets the usual kazayis size piece of challah). So what should one do?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill That's position 3. He's asking according to positions 1 and 2 in the question which AFAIK are more mainstream. So goes to show what one thinks is mainstream and not :)

Comment: What would you do if your host served something you don't think is kosher eg chalav stam, non glatt meat, chodosh, turkey etc. ? It probably depends how bad you think the food in question is and how offensive it will be for you to avoid eating it.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I think this is a different question from kashrus. Here the question impacts one's ability to fulfill the mitzvah of seudas Shabbos (and perhaps even kiddush). The kashrus question is, like you say, a question of deciding what you can avoid and what you can't (unless the kashrus is so bad you must avoid everything?). But you can't really avoid having a seudah.

Comment: @Curiouser First of all, I think it's the same question, just with it being not so bad to eat the food and very embarrassing to skip the whole seudah. The question is, was this really kiddush bemakom seudah because if not, you can't eat anything yet as you haven't heard kiddush! You see that not being able to eat everything can be talui on the kashrut issues of very few products. Fulfilling the positive commandment of seudot shabbat is more of a side point as **usually** you can find some bread or matza later at home.

Comment: @Curiouser, I don't think the question should focus on Kiddush b'makom seudah, which can be fulfilled with cakes, etc.  Also, what is your question's concern.  What would opinion #1/2 do?  They would eat more pas.  But we don't do that?- That's b/c we hold like #3.

Comment: @Curiouser, tangentially related, I think a question could be asked the other way.  We tend to overestimate the size of a beitza.  We should probably more often than not be making hamotzi on our pas haba b'kisnin.  Since it is pas, the litmus test should be the opposite- Why shouldn't I be making hamotzi?

Comment: @YDK: I don't mean to open up an argument about whether psak halachah as it stands regarding a beitza is correct or not. As for kiddush b'makom seudah, I said "perhaps" parenthetically, so I'm not sure why you think that is a focus. And the Aruch HaShulchan says like #1, and many poskim treat him as a posek acharon (see Shut Bnei Banim) so I don't think the question is baseless.

Comment: @Curiouser, my main point wasn't the beitza, but that we should be reversing the litmus test.  So when you ask what should he do, what is your concern?

Comment: @YDK: My concern is how one should behave in such a situation. Does one need to make another meal on bread when he gets home? Is there some logical leniency to apply? Does he wash without a bracha and say mezonos so as not to stick out and offend anyone? Should he ask for real bread? etc

Comment: @Curiouser, ah, so how to approach the safek bracha l'vatala.

Comment: Dear OP: These are not three mutually exclusive Positions. Really, these are three Cases. If any of the three Cases come up, then you must wash and say hamotzi on a mezonos item. You seem to be arguing that, in Case 3, you shouldn't wash or say hamotzi. But R' Luban implies that the _Mishnah Berurah_ says that, in Case 3, you _must_ wash and say hamotzi. Are you saying that the _Mishnah Berurah_ is wrong? And if so, why is he wrong? Please edit the question to clarify it, then ping me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just rely on it being hamotzi for many reasons:

- It is a chidush of the shulchan aruch in the first place that the
  category of pas haba b'kisnin is so broad, many rishonim would have
  made hamotzi even on babka.
- I didn't listen to the shiur, but I would guess that some might argue that
  chocolate chip challah is not the same as babka since it is still
  intended to be bread and is being used as bread by people.
- "Position 3" is likely the main position one should follow.
  Especially when one is clearly being kovea seudah with his meal (and
  eating something so bread-like), it makes sense to make hamotzi.

Btw, the gemara suggests that the host give out large pieces of challah, so they shouldn't just be a kezayis.

Comment: The question assumes that the person does not hold position 3, and it assumes that R. Sobolofky's psak is correct, as well as the Shulchan Aruch's psak about pas haba b'kisnin. So I'm not sure how any of your points helps.

Comment: He's saying that even R Sobolofsky would agree to be meikil because it's such a sha'at hadechak. [I don't mean he's _actually_ quoting R Sobolofsky...] If you are sooo sure about your psak than there is no question: you simply cannot eat anything till they bring you real bread or more chocolate chip challah (or some more other cake/cracker) so that you can have kiddush bemakom seudah.

Comment: @Curiouser, few people have such strong views against 'position 3', i think Artscroll brachos book says it depends on the food being eaten, so this would be a 'position 3' case. i doubt a posek would say u can't be yotzei with a hamotzi in such a situation, esp. considering that making a mezonos is prob. a bigger kula.

Comment: Ariel, what is your source for your first bullet?  I recall from R'Moshe (I need to find where) that those deserts cited by the SA were actually bread that had a filling or other taste added, but everyone would agree that our cakes are pas haba b'kisnin.

Comment: @ArielK: I appreciate your logic, but I really would like sources for "few people would say" etc. Poskim do pasken like certain positions and many Jews follow specific poskim consistently, so it's not really a fair answer to argue against my question unless you have evidence that position 3 really is so dominant to overrule the others.

Comment: @YDK, see the OU article from the question. Each rishon explains pas haba bkisnin as being a different food. However, some try saying the different definitions may not be mutually exclusive (see footnote 4).

Comment: @ArielK according to you, shouldn't you make a ha-motzi on babka? Why should you be meikel for this but not machmir?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the information provided I think you really only have one option.

Ask the host if they have any plain bread.  To avoid insulting the host, avoid eating any chocolate during the entire meal.

If they do not have any bread, then eat the rest of the meal, and be sure to say a bracha before each item.

When you get home, or leave, or you go back to shul, see if you can get yourself a small "Seuda"

Comment: Why can't you eat the chocolate chip bread for ha-motzi, and ask for some plain bread separately?

Comment: @wfb because you didn't say the bracha for it.  This is all assuming that you find choclate chip chalah to not be bread.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you are kove'a seudah, by eating it with bread at the meal, no?

Comment: @wfb if you are kove'a seudah with the 'cake' then why do you need the bread?

Answer (score -3):

You wash and say hamotzi and you do not embarrass your host. Just because you are frum does not mean that you can't be a mensch.

Comment: A source that this is correct behaviour would enhance the quality of this answer.

Comment: Presumably this would not be the case if the host was serving pork.  How do you qualify that?  Where did you get this from?